# Xpath-How to extract a particular word from the text()?

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

Can anyone help me how to extract particular word from the text() from the Xpath expression

I'm currently scrapping the names of the coins from Website:https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/

have used the Xpath expression:
`(//h1[@class='priceHeading']/text())[1]`

which has 'Bitcoin Price' I just need the first word 'Bitcoin' ignoring the rest.

Don't mind my mistakes, I'm a newbie here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it kind of depends upon what you can rely on, and which version of XPath you are using. Whether a space is sufficient, or if you would want some more sophisticated tokenization is largely dependent on the data and your requirements.

With XPath 1.0 and later, you can use [`substring-before()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-substring-before) a space

```
substring-before((//h1[@class='priceHeading']/text())[1], ' ')
```

With XPath 2.0 and later, you can use [`tokenize()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-tokenize) and select the first item

```
tokenize((//h1[@class='priceHeading']/text())[1], ' ')[1]
```

If you know that it will always end with " `Price`" then you could use that value instead of just a space in the `substring-before()` or `tokenize()`, or could [`replace()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-replace) " `Price`" with "`''`":

```
replace((//h1[@class='priceHeading']/text())[1], ' Price', '')
```